# Minimizing cost function

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, gradient-descent

In the definition, the unbounded signal (or data) is the signal that can take infinite value and to make it bounded we can normalize it and then it will $\in L_\infty$.

In control theory, and especially in adapive control if we have the following system:
$y(t)=\theta^*u(t)$

where $\theta^*$ is unknown parameter; $u$ and $y$ are measurment signals but they are **not necessary** to be **bounded**

To estimate the unknown parameter $\theta^*$ we present estimate model:

$\hat{y}(t)=\theta\hat{u}(t)$

where $\theta$ is the estimating of $\theta^*$

The update law or adaptive law that can give the estimation we can generate it by using the following minimization problem of gardient method:

$J=\frac{1}{2}(y-\theta u)^2$

where we have to minimize the cost function with respect to $\theta$ 
**But** If the signals $u$ and $y$ not guranteed to be bounded then the minimization problem is ill-posed, therefore in the estimating process we have to normalize the signals $u$ and $y$ to make it bounded and that as following:

$\bar{y}=\frac{y}{m}$

$\bar{u}=\frac{u}{m}$

where $m$ is the normalizing signal it is given by : $m^2=1+n^2$ and we choose $n$ such that $\frac{y}{m},\frac{u}{m}\in L_\infty$ i.e. to be bounded.

the question: if $u$ and $y$ unbounded, why the minimization problem is ill-posed?

Comment: What spaces do any of those objects live in?  You tagged optimal control, so do you mean you have a functional $J = \int_{0}^{T} \dfrac{1}{2} (y(t)-\theta(t)u(t))^2dt$ and $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ might not be bounded functions?  Otherwise, the global minimizer is $\theta^* = y/u$ because the problem is convex, as long as $u\neq 0$.

Comment: @Renard The space is $R$ and the question is for scalar variables where $y$ and $u$ are measurable signals and $\theta$ is the parameter that minimizes the cost function.

Comment: So $y$ and $\theta$ are real-valued, and you are minimizing $\mathbb{E}_{y,u}[.5 (y-\theta u)^2]$?  Or $y$ and $\theta$ are measurable functions of some underlying random variable $x$?

Comment: @Renard $y,u$ are functions of time and they represent the input and output of a control system where $y=\theta^*u$ and $\theta^*$ is unknown. and the problem of minimization is written in a book as $\underset{\theta}{min}J(\theta)=\underset{\theta}{min}\frac{(y-\theta u)^2}{2}$ where $\theta$ is the estimation of $\theta^*$

Answer (score 0):

You may consider $u$ and $y$ as a gauge, and if they are not bounded then simply your function will change freely. If you want to optimize, $u$ and $y$ can vary and result in failure to optimize.

Comment: Even if $y$ and $u$ change freely, also $\theta$ will change to keep the minimizing of function. I think it is simple problem but i can not understand it well.

Comment: @amd yes there will be some theta to assuming  you are minimizing the total function but it will fail to minimize because changing y or u you may also reach better minimization for every theta.

Comment: What is meant with the "function will change freely"?

Comment: @SampleTime as I understood, It means when $u$ and $y$ change the cost function will change regardless of $\theta$. If you have any comment please share it.

Comment: @amd The question is still unclear to me, see for example the comment by Renard. What do you mean by "measureable signals", does that mean that $u$ and $y$ are functions of time? If thats the case your cost function is most likely wrong.

Comment: @SampleTime I have written in a comment above more details I hope it help.

Comment: @amd Are you sure there is no integral/limit/expectation in the cost function definition?

Comment: @SampleTime not for this specific question but  if you are dealing with a linearly expressed coat function actually integration will be so simplified so that integral turns out to be a just multiplication (I mean the area above a line).

Comment: @SampleTime Yes sure, I don't know if I can share a link but you can see the minimizing problem in a book "Robust Adaptive Control" it is available for reading in Google Book. the pag 163 https://books.google.ru/books/about/Robust_Adaptive_Control.html?id=pXWFY_vbg1MC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @amd Why don't you just write down the problem in a proper and correct way here on this page (preferably by editing your original question)?

Comment: 163 isn't in the preview. "Robust" often means we're going to prove a property of an estimator or maximizer even when $\mathbb{E}$ is mis specified. But that decision usually still depends on what set of CDFs or PDFs is under consideration. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @SampleTime I have reformulated the question.

Comment: @Renard I have reformulated the question.